# How to print multiple tables into one pdf

Tags: qt, qpainter, qpixmap, qprinter

I'm trying to print multiple table (qtablewidget) objects in single pdf using qt.

I can print one table, using the code provided in(https://forum.qt.io/topic/80501/qpainter-howto-draw-table/7)

```
QPixmap pix(widget->size());
QPainter painter(&pix);
widget->render(&painter);
painter.end();
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf"); // will be in build folder

painter.begin(&printer);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pix);
painter.end();
```

However, if I try to print multiple tables, the code fails. If I create multiple QPainters, qt just outputs multiple pdfs, with one table in each pdf. I'm trying to do it using one QPainter and multiple QPixmaps, but no success so far.

Would anyone please let me know how I can get around it?

Any help would be appreciated

Regards,

Comment: Side note: a `QTableWidget` is not a table. It is an UI for a table, but it was not designed to be printable. It would look better if you rendered the table to html and then printed that using Qt's formatted text system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the code fail? The below should work (I didn't test it). Note the absence of manual object lifetime management: let the compiler do it for you. A `QPainter` is a proper C++ class and knows how to release its resources without having to manually invoke `QPainter::end()`.

```
void printWidgets(QWidgetList widgets) {
  QVector<QPixmap> pixmaps;
  for (auto *w : widgets) {
    QPixmap pix(w->size());
    QPainter painter(pix);
    w->render(&painter);
    pixmaps.push_back(pix);
  }

  QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
  printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
  printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
  printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
  printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf"); // will be in build folder

  QPainter painter(&printer);
  QPoint pos;    
  for (auto &pix : qAsConst(pixmaps)) {
    painter.drawPixmap(pos, pix);
    pos.ry() += pix.height(); // stack the output vertically
  }
}
```